# ionic deeplinks with angular 8

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, deep-linking

when i use external link to open my app, i have no deepliks in this code :

```
      this.deeplinks
    .route({
      "/reset_password": ResetPasswordPage,
    })
    .subscribe(
      (match) => {
        alert("match");
        alert(JSON.stringify(match.$link));
      },
      (nomatch) => {
        alert("nomatch");
        alert(JSON.stringify(nomatch));
      }
    );
```

with the url app.myapp.io/reset_password, i enter in the nomatch clause with values

```
{"$url":{"url":"myapp://","path":"", "scheme:"myapp", host:""},...}
```

and for all urls it's the same way ...

config :

- angular : 8.1
- ionic : 5.36
- cordova (no capacitor)
- cordova-android :10.1.2

in package.json

```
"ionic-plugin-deeplinks": "^1.0.24",
```

and into cordova/plugins

```
  "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": {
    "URL_SCHEME": "myapp",
    "DEEPLINK_SCHEME": "https",
    "DEEPLINK_HOST": "app.myapp.io",
    "ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX": "/"
  },
```

in config.xml (android) i've added

to android platform
but no plugin config for deeplinks in it

the deeplink configuration is correct?
what is wrong?

thx for help